# Proving a statement about a continuous function for which $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\exists y>x : f(y)>f(x)$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Suppose $f$ is a function which is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Also, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $y>x$ such that $f(y)>f(x)$. I must prove that if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L$ then $f(x)<L$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I proved the following hint: for all $M>0$ there exists $y>M$ such that $f(y)>f(a)$ for a given $a \in \mathbb{R}$. But I fail to see how to use it in the proof. I tried assuming that the statement is false, i.e. that there exists $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(b) \geq L$, but I simply don't know what to do next (I tried using the definition of limit). Any suggestions?

Comment: Let $E$ be the set $\{ x \mid x>b, f(x)> f(b)\}$. $E$ is non-empty by hypothesis. Also, the limit condition gives that $E$ is bounded above. Set $y=\sup E$ and use your first hypothesis to obtain a contradiction that $y=\sup E$..

Comment: @DavidMitra - $b$ is an arbitary fixed number? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit off, but easily fixed: assume $f(b')\ge L$. Then choose $b$  ($>b'$) so that $f(b)>L$. Now use the above.

Comment: @DavidMitra - how one can prove that $E$ is bounded from above using the limit condition? Using Heine's definition of limit?

Comment: Otherwise, there would be $x_n\rightarrow\infty$ with $f(x_n)>f(b)> L$ for each $n$. But then we can't have $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=L$. (I'm not sure what Heine's definition is.)

Comment: @DavidMitra - Heine's definition of limit is an equivalent definition of limit using sequences. When $x_n \to \infty$, $f(x_n)\to L$ precisely because $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=L$ (this limit is equvalent to saying that for any $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to \infty$, $f(x_n)\to L$).

Comment: @DavidMitra one things bugs me, though -- I am convinced with this argument, yet it does not look like we are using the assumption that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @ClementC.You'll use that to obtain the contradiction. By continuity of $f$, $f(y)\ge f(b)$. Now, there is a $z>y$ with $f(z)>f(y)$. But then, this $z$ must belong to $E$ and also exceeds $y$.

Comment: Oh, I see -- thanks.

Comment: Which makes me wonder: is there a simple or easy counterexample if one does not assume continuity? (I may ask that as a separate question, if the answer is not immediate)

Comment: @ClementC.  Take $f(x)=\pi x$ for $x<1$ and $f(x)=\arctan x$ for $x\ge 1$. You can even set things up so that $f(x_n)>L$ with $x_n\rightarrow\infty$ by introducing " / " shapes with the top open and whose heights tend to zero (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Hmmm... thanks! indeed, that settles the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (more or less complete) outline.

Your $f$ satisfies

$\ \ \ $ 1) $f$ is continuous

$\ \ \ $ 2) $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=L<\infty$.

$\ \ \ $ 3) For each $x$, there is a  $y>x$ with $f(y)>f(x)$.

Proceeding by contradiction:

Suppose $b'$ is such that $f(b')\ge L$. Using 3), choose $b$ such that $f(b)>f(b')$.

Now set 
$$
E=\{   x\mid f(x)>f(b)\ \text{and}\ x>b\} .
$$

Use  3) to show $E$ is non-empty.

Use  2) to show $E$ is bounded above (note $x\in E\Rightarrow f(x)>f(b)>L$ here).

Set $y=\sup E$.

Now use 1) to show  that $f(y)\ge f(b)$.

Finally, use 3) again to find a   $z>y$ with $f(z)>f(y)$ and argue that this contradicts the fact that $y$ is the supremum of $E$.